# How to call a function only once for a specific argument in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I have a simple function with two arguments.

```html
<script>
function addError(element, error_msg) {
    element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div class='error'>" + error_msg + "</div>");
}
</script>
```

I want that when  we call this function with arguments  like - `addError(elem_1, "Error message");`. This function should not call again with the same **first argument(elem_1)**. It can be called with the different arguments but can not be called with the same **first argument(elem_1)**. How can I do this?

Comment: @hev1 I am new to javascript so, I couldn't understand your code. If there is any easy way to do it, I will love to know.

Comment: My method is quite simple. What part do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `WeakSet` to store the first arguments the function has been invoked with.

```js
function uniquifyFirstArg(fn){
    const set = new WeakSet;
    return function(first, ...rest){
        if(!set.has(first)){
            set.add(first);
            fn(first, ...rest);
        }
    }
}
const addError = uniquifyFirstArg(function(element, error_msg) {
    element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div class='error'>" + error_msg + "</div>");
});
addError(document.body, "This is an error");
addError(document.querySelector('body'), "Not shown");
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Better use a `WeakSet` to avoid memory leaks, if only objects are passed for the parameter

Comment: @Bergi Nice suggestion.